# Why custom callback doesn't work in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a custom callback in my ActiveRecord model.
Here is the example:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  define_callbacks :my_method
  set_callback :my_method, :after, :callback_method

  def my_method
    run_callbacks :my_method
  end

  def callback_method
    # Do smth
  end
end
```

My callback method never invoked but no error message exist. What i doing wrong?
Thnks!

(Ruby 1.8.7-p371, rails 3.2.13)

Comment: I found out that this article was very enlightned on the subject: http://www.intridea.com/blog/2012/3/22/define-custom-callbacks-for-activerecord-and-more

Comment: I used that article too, but still no result in my code

Comment: `:after` what? After save? After creation? Why not use one of the callbacks listed in the [list of available callbacks](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks)?

Comment: It because i use state machine in that model and i want to invoke a callback only after getting a specific state (after invoking my_method)

Comment: do you use a gem for your state machine like this: https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine ?

Comment: i use https://github.com/geekq/workflow